# Significance of unity in ring for isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

(This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra Chapter 18 Exercise J6.)

1. Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
2. For each element $a$ in $A$, the function $\pi_a$ defined by $\pi_a(x)=ax$ satisfies the identity $\pi_a(x+y)=\pi_a(x)+\pi_a(y)$.
3. Let $\mathscr{A}$ denote the set $\{\pi_a: a\in A\}$ with the two operations:
   \begin{align*}
       [\pi_a + \pi_b](x) &= \pi_a(x) + \pi_b(x) \quad \text{and}\quad \pi_a\pi_b = \pi_a\circ\pi_b
   \end{align*}
4. Let $\phi: A\rightarrow\mathscr{A}$ such that $\phi(a)=\pi_a$.

> Prove that if $A$ has a unity, then $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

It can be verified that $\mathscr{A}$ is a ring, and that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Question:

If we construct the inverse function $\phi^{-1}: \mathscr{A}\rightarrow A$ such that $\phi^{-1}(\pi_a)=a$, wouldn't it be sufficient to show the bijection between $\mathscr{A}$ and $A$, and therefore $\phi$ an isomorphism? What is the significance of having unity in this question?

Answer (score 1):

If the ring does not have unity, the map $\phi$ may fail to be injective, i.e., there may exist nonzero $a \in A$ such that $ax = 0$ for all $x \in A$. Your supposed inverse is not well-defined in this case. For example, for each prime $p$ one can define a ring of order $p$ with the additive structure of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ but where the product of any two elements is $0$. In this case, the map $\phi$ is trivial.

If the ring does have unity, then if $a \in ker\phi$ in particular implies
$$a = a \cdot 1 = 0,$$
thus $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your example, but I agree the existence of unity in $A$ is to ensure the injectivity of $\phi$.  Specifically, $\phi(a)=\phi(b)\implies\pi_a=\pi_b$ for $a,b\in A$.  In particular, $\pi_a(1)=\pi_b(1)\implies a=b$.